# Recording videos with audio in Ubuntu

Tags: video, youtube

I'm trying to put together a video blog for you tube, and I'm looking for a software application where I can use the webcam to record video and also some way to record audio.

I've checked out wxCam and Gmerlin, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Cheese? It working fine for me as multi-shot or put some effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try XVidCap, search that in the software center

Answer (score 0):

gtk-recordmydesktop it's a good option too.